# PHP Contact script errors in one function

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have HTML and PHP code for contact form. When someone type characters like this: š, đ, ž, č, and ć (UTF-8) characters, script reports few errors.

**1. How can I add UTF-8 input in $first_name and $last_name input forms?**

Next problem is, message of error or success is poping up by Java Script pop up. If I type in name box "šđžčć" and in last name box "šđžčć" script is reprting three mesages:

1. Wrong name
2. Wrong last name
3. Please try again (not exactly like this but some message)

And that means - three pop up windows! You get one - you close it, then second - close it too, etc etc, and it's frustrating. My secong question:

**2. How can I rewrite this PHP and put all messages and errors in one function/value/message and make just one pop up says: Wrong name, last name, i love you etc.**

PHP code:

```html
<?php
 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
     
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
 
    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
 
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";
 
     
 
     
 
    function died($error) {
 
        // your error code can go here
 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('error')</script>";
 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('these errors apears below')</script>";
 
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('please fix errors')</script>";
 
        die();
 
    }
 
     
 
    // validation expected data exists
 
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
 
        died(<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted successfully!')</script>');       
 
    }
 
     
 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
 
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
 
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
 
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
 
     
 
    $error_message = "";
 
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
 
    $error_message .= '<script type='text/javascript'>alert('wrong email !')</script>';
 
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
 
    $error_message .= '<script type='text/javascript'>alert('invalid firs name')</script>';
 
  }
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
 
    $error_message .= '<script type='text/javascript'>alert('invalid last name')</script>';
 
  }
 
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
 
    $error_message .= '<script type='text/javascript'>alert('invalid message')</script>';
 
  }
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
 
    died($error_message);
 
  }
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
 
    function clean_string($string) {
 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
 
     
 
     
 
// create email headers
 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 
?>
 
 
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
 
 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted successfully!')</script>"
 
 
 
<?php
 
}
 
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I need pop up for this